# why is chrome pulling the bottom elements up after a relatively positioned element?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

here's something i never thought i would type: chrome breaks the layout, but IE (or any other browser for that matter) doesnt...

there's a featured slider with position: relative; with elements inside with position: absolute;

the javascript loops through the elements to create a rotating images

see: http://guardianweb.edulence.com/model10/

i've added a margin-top of 304px to the two elements below the featured slider, but the gap is huge in every browser besides google chrome

Comment: May be related to this http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/0a66b577b7036a14?pli=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that other browsers are incorrectly applying a height of 305px and width of 940px to your `#featured` division. I have no idea why they'd do that. Chrome is **correctly** rendering that element with a height of 0, because there is no content inside the element (absolutely positioned elements don't take up any space in the flow of the document).

**In Chrome:**

[image: Chrome element]

**In Firefox:**

[image: Firefox element]

I suppose one way you could work around this *is* to manually specify the width and height on your `#featured` element so that all the browsers, including Chrome, act the same.

Comment: ahhhh of course Chrome is the only browser that is doing this correctly. thanks for the help :)

Comment: The browsers aren't applying the inline height and width, the plugin is.  Seemed kind of like chrome was the one reporting a funny `innerHeight` but the page changed before I could narrow it down.  The plugin is supposed to resize the div if it doesn't have any size set.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is here:

```
// stretch container
var reshape = opts.containerResize && !$cont.innerHeight();
if (reshape) { // do this only if container has no size http://tinyurl.com/da2oa9
    var maxw = 0, maxh = 0;
    for(var j=0; j < els.length; j++) {
        var $e = $(els[j]), e = $e[0], w = $e.outerWidth(), h = $e.outerHeight();
        if (!w) w = e.offsetWidth || e.width || $e.attr('width');
        if (!h) h = e.offsetHeight || e.height || $e.attr('height');
        maxw = w > maxw ? w : maxw;
        maxh = h > maxh ? h : maxh;
    }
    if (maxw > 0 && maxh > 0)
        $cont.css({width:maxw+'px',height:maxh+'px'});
}
```

`!$cont.innerHeight()` seems to be false in chrome but true in other browsers.  This is causing the plugin to set a specific height and width to the div where as in chrome no height is set, meaning it is still 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Chrome's fault. If you inspect the `#featured` element, you'll notice that this element has a height and width set via CSS inline styles in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Firefox: `<div id="featured" style="width: 940px; height: 305px;">`

Chrome: `<div id="featured">`

The height of that DIV is zero in Chrome.

That `style` attribute is added to the DIV via JavaScript, so you'll have to figure out why it's added for Firefox, but not for Chrome...